# Excluding Dates Using BETWEEN

Tags: sql-server-2016

I'm trying to use the BETWEEN function to exclude dates that fall between two parameter dates, but my current code is also excluding NULL occurrences.  I have a query that includes account records that may or may not contain a 'Closed Date'. My current code partially works, but I don't want it to exclude NULL records that don't contain a Closed Date at all.

```
WHERE ta.ROW_PROCESSED_THRU = '20190731'
  AND NOT CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),ta.CLOSED_DATE,112) BETWEEN '20190701' AND '20190731'
```

Comment: Based on your comments left on already posted answers, I suspect the addition of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be rather helpful so the community has a better idea about what you're looking for.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
 AND (NOT (ta.CLOSED_DATE >= '20190701' AND ta.CLOSED_DATE < '20190801') 
    OR ta.CLOSED_DATE IS NULL)
```

Comment: You should add some detail to your answer showing why `BETWEEN` is terrible for this versus your proposed change.

Comment: I was initially getting an error related to the "AND", but it was just because the first parentheses should be after the "AND" and not before it.                      
                                                                                                                       AND (NOT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),tm.DATE_CLOSE, 112) BETWEEN @strFirstofMonth AND @strLastofMonth)
  OR tm.DATE_CLOSE IS NULL)

Comment: The AND should be outside the parentheses, not inside.

Comment: @Mike you have 2 answers without using CONVERT. Why do you insist on its use? What's the type of the column?

Answer (score 3):

To include the NULLs you need to add an explicit NULL predicate. Also, the convert function may significantly degrade your query's performance, much better would be to explicitly state the date range with two predicates:

```
AND ( NOT (ta.CLOSED_DATE >= '20190701' AND ta.CLOSED_DATE < '20190801') 
    OR ta.CLOSED_DATE IS NULL)
```

HTH

Comment: I should clarify, that I DO want to include NULL occurrences.  Some records may contain a Closed Date, and some may not.  I just want to exclude occurrences when the Closed Date is between the two parameter dates, while still INCLUDING records with a NULL Closed Date or a Closed Date that's outside of the two parameter dates

Comment: For some reason this was only filtering in just the NULL occurrences, which could have been an error on my part

Comment: @ypercube thanks for the edit ! :-) <thumb up>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include null you can map it to a value outside the range that's exluded, i.e.:

```
WHERE ta.ROW_PROCESSED_THRU = '20190731'
  AND  COALESCE(ta.CLOSED_DATE, '00000000') NOT BETWEEN '20190701' AND '20190731'
```

Comment: A little confusing and I ultimately wasn't able to get it to work correctly, but it was likely due to my inexperience

Comment: Your secret is safe with us, what problem did you encounter?

Comment: Watch out using 0 as a placeholder for the epoch.  While 0 is the epoch for datetime, it won't work for datetime2, but having one argument as 0 will cause the engine to try and coerce closed_date (in this example) into a datetime, which may or may not work since datetime2 can hold values outside the range of a datetime.  see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208741/what-does-0-in-datediffminute-0-date-actually-mean

Comment: I beleive this is a string, and its not used for anything but as a value guaranteed outside the intervall. I used  '0000....' but could have used '15000101' equally well